# Mysql CONVERT integer TEXT field substring character limit

Tags: mysql, integer

I have a simple database with 1 table and a number of fields, one of them a text field that always has the same alpha prefix followed by a 3 character player name and then number which can range from 1 to 100.

The text record looks like this and is the result of a LOAD LOCAL INFILE command form a third party application generated .txt file.

GRAND CHAMPION
MAC   1,180,611,620

TOP ANGLERS
1) MAC     963,956,660
2) MAC     777,545,450
3) MAC     774,563,200
4) MAC     659,721,170

BIGGEST LIAR
DVA
6 FISH   4 TALES

TOP BOAT ROCKER
MAC
24 ROCK BOATS

Using PHP I am attempting to convert the numeric value following DVA to an integer and order it from largest to smallest.  My PHP code to display only the block from BIGGEST LIAR to 4 tales is as follows.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE tablestats LIKE '%biggest liar%' ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING(tablestats, LOCATE('LIAR', tablestats) +5), SIGNED INTEGER),tablestats DESC LIMIT 5;")

or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
echo substr($info['tablestats'],151,40);
Print "<br>";
} 
?>
```

This generates a page with the text I'm looking for which ends up rendering as

BIGGEST LIAR DVA 6 FISH 4 TALES

however with multiple records where the variable following the 3 character username changes, ordering with DESC does not seem to work correctly. I've noticed that when the numbers are singular (1 to 9) it seems ok but if the value is over 10 then an instance where one record is 6 and the other is 10 results in 6 listing before 10.

What I'm trying to do here is specify the numeric value following one space after the 3 character username which takes into account that the number here may be 1 to 100 and then convert that to integer and order.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Tony.

Comment: The key problem is the data is not normalised. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization ) Are you able to normalise the database?

Comment: I can try to clean it up a bit but it's the result of the import and the fact that a 3rd party app is creating it.

Comment: Transform the data before ... or after ... it hits your database.

Comment: Python is pretty good for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking into using something like this:

```
SELECT *, 
  CONVERT(
     SUBSTRING(tablestats, 
               LOCATE('LIAR ', tablestats) + LENGTH('LIAR ') + 4), 
     SIGNED INTEGER)
FROM stats 
WHERE tablestats LIKE '%biggest liar%' 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19d59/3)

Uses your search string, LIAR in this case, and adds 4 characters per your statement -- character name is always 3 characters.  If this is not true, you can use LOCATE again to find the next space.

BTW -- using the CONVERT method like this doesn't work in other RDBMS.  MySQL converts the numeric values it finds up until the first non-numeric value.  Hence the reason you don't have to remove the rest of the string before converting.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. This seems to work fine if I only have the block BIGGEST LIAR DVA 633 FISH 4 TALES (multiple 3 digit values) in the varchar field. If I have the entire text field included in the original example it doesn't seem to convert the value following LIAR (4 characters) to an integer. I'll keep experimenting.